# script le campo de emails no googledocs

Tags: javascript, planilha

Ola, eu tenho uma planilha no GoogleDocs, que possui um campo com um ou mais emails, neste caso, seperados por virgula. O script le o campo e envia um email para o destinario registrado no email do campo. Porem, o email so ẽ recebido pelo destinario se ele estiver sozinho no campo. Se contiver mais de um email, ninguem recebe. Por ex, se o registro contiver dois emails separados por virgula, como em "a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com", ninguem recebeç se contiver apenas a@gmail.com, entao recebe normalmente. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é lido esses campos e como é enviado o email? Provavelmente quando há 2 ou mais emails, o script que envia lê tudo como se fosse apenas 1 email e não dá certo pq vai como email inválido.

Comment: Eu pego todos os emails do campo com esse codigo:                       var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7];
E envio com esse:   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});

Comment: nao ha uma solucao, entao...tipo, o script le ate encontrar uma virgula e enviar o email, logo em seguida, le o q tem apos a virgula e envia tambem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está meu codigo. Eu adaptei com a sua solução, mas tá dando um erro:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows


  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
     var expire = dataRange[i][8]; 

    if (expire < 10) {
      var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7];
      var subject = "Você tem um prazo de auditoria vencendo em " + dataRange[i][8] + " dias";
      var emails = emailAddress.split(",");
      var dataEnvio = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][0], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var dataFim = Utilities.formatDate(dataRange[i][4], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      var message = "<P><i style='color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight:bold';> *Esta é a Proposta de encaminhamento da COAUD, de " + dataEnvio + "\n" + ", que deve ser respondida até "  
      + dataFim + "<P><a style='color: black; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold';>Identificação do Documento: </a>" + dataRange[i][2] + "<P><b style='color: black; font-size: 12px; "
      + " font-weight:bold';> Recomendação de Auditoria: </b> " + dataRange[i][3] 
      +"<P> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
      + "------------------------------------------------</P>" 
      + "<P><i style='color: red; font-size: 10px';> NOTA: Amparada na Portaria X monitoramento. Para acessá-lo, consulte o manual de monitoramento, disponível "  
      + "<A href='https://www.a.x'>aqui</A>. Contate a COA pelos telefones: XXXXXXXX/6779 e e-mail: coa@tir.br, para maiores informações </i></P>";
     // for (var email of emails) {
           MailApp.sendEmail(Email.trim(), subject, "", {htmlBody: message});


//  MailApp.sendEmail(Email.trim(), emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
   }

}
```

}

Comment: So lembrando q eu já tinha um for...agora, esta um for dentro do outro...

Answer (score 0):

Quebre o valor do campo em array e chame a função que envia os emails dentro de um `for...of`. Desta forma cada endereço de email será enviado de forma separada para a função, e não tudo junto quando há mais de 1 email no campo:

```
// quebro a variável emailAddress em array pela vírgula
var Emails = emailAddress.split(",");
for(var Email of Emails){
   // o .trim() é importante para eliminar espaços
   MailApp.sendEmail(Email.trim(), subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Comment: Ok, mas onde eu passo o parametro do campo q contem o email? no codigo original, ele busca o email em uma célula [i][7], por exemplo, linha 1, coluna 7 da planilha, e armazena na variavel emailAddressvar. Daí, o script le o q esta nessa variavel e envia o email. Nesse codigo q vc enviou, como ficaria? ele nao esta passando emailAddress = dataRange[i][7] como parametro. Grato.

Comment: A variável `emailAddressvar` não muda, fica como está. O código que coloquei apenas está convertendo o valor em array para que possa ser enviado um por um caso haja mais de 1 email na célula.

Comment: O parâmetro agora é `Email.trim()`, que é cada email na célula.

Comment: Da a mensagem "Falta ; depois do inicializador for-loop. (linha 25, arquivo "Envia_Email"). Porem, eu não sei onde colocar ";". Ja tentei despois do for e não rola.;

Comment: No for, a variável "Email" deve começar o "E" maiúsculo: `for (var Email of emails) {`... você colocou com "e" minúsculo: `for (var email of emails) {`

Comment: Sim, eu já corrigi isso...esqueci de mencionar na msg anterior]...mas o mesmo erro continua. Obrigado.

Comment: Que linha 25 é essa do erro?

Comment: è a linha do for... for (var email of emails) {

Comment: Então eu não sei o que pode ser. O `for` não precisa de `;`. Esse código deveria funcionar tranquilo, já que ele apenas está separando os emails pela vírgula e mandando pra função um por um separados.

Comment: Será que não tem relacao com esse aninhamento? Eu tenho um for, um if dentro do for, e um outro for dentro do if...de uma olhada. Grato.

Comment: Creio que não haja problemas no aninhamento. O for é síncrono: veja, ele entra no primeiro for, entra no if e então no segundo for. Após processar o segundo for, ele volta pro primeiro e assim sucessivamente. Faça um teste com console.log. Crie uma função teste() e coloque um console.log para ver se os emails estão indo... peraí que vou fazer um JSFiddle pra vc ver....

Comment: Veja como ficaria: https://jsfiddle.net/vvmxLrgn/

Comment: Aí é só observar o console para ver se irão aparecer os emails

Comment: Ele não envia os emails porque qdo envia ele cai na minha caixa postal. Isso acontece quando eu tenho apenas um email no campo. Se eu tiver mais de um, separado por virgula, como é o caso, não envia.

Comment: O erro estava no for. Eu comentei(dê uma olhada no código atualizado). E já está enviando email para os 2 destinatários no campo. Posso deixar assim mesmo?

Comment: Testei com 3 emails e envia para os 3. Que massa!

Comment: Estranho, não era pra funcionar não rs.. acho que o erro estava que vc não havia fechado o for com a chave }

Comment: Ok, esta funcionando sem o for. Mas pq vc acha q eh necessario? Estou temendo remove-lo do codigo e ter algum efeito indesejado.

Comment: Veja só: essa variável `Email.trim()` vinha do `for`... sem o `for` deveria dar erro, porque a variável fica sem origem nenhuma... faz um teste: deixa o for, fecha ele com `}` e altere o "email" para "Email" (com "E" maiúsculo).

Comment: Tem que ficar exatamente assim: https://jsfiddle.net/vvmxLrgn/1/

Comment: Estranho, pq realmente nao funciona desse jeito. Bem, vou manter sem o for e se tiver algum problema, volto aqui novamente. Muito obrigado, e boa tarde.